# Problem with passing JSON payload to django REST api using requests library

Tags: json, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I getting started with Django REST API, and following [This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c708Nf0cHrs&t=2330s)

my client code is:

```
import requests

endpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api"

get_response = requests.get(endpoint,params={"abc":123},json={'query' : 'HELLO WORLD!!'})
print(get_response.json()
```

my api code is:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json

def api_home(request):
    body = request.body
    print(body)
    data = {}
    try:
        data = json.loads(body)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    print(data) # returns {}
    dtat["content_type"] = request.content_type
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Here the body is supposed to contain the 'byte string of JSON data' being sent by the client and `print(body)` is supposed to print `b'{'query' : 'HELLO WORLD!!'}'` but the result am getting is `b'{}'` and exception `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` from the try: except. The JsonResponse returns `{"content_type": "text/plain"}` to the client where as it should have been `{"content_type" : "application/json"}`

can someone help me with what am doing wrong and how i can fix it

modified code after googling solution ended up with same exception.

```
import requests
import json

endpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api"

payload = {'query': 'HELLO WORLD!!'}

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

get_response = requests.get(endpoint, params={"abc": 123}, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

print(get_response.text)
```

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json

def api_home(request):
    data = {}
    try:
        data = json.loads(request.body)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    print(data)
    data["content_type"] = request.content_type
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: It is unusual to pass JSON data in the body of a GET request. Maybe Django is just ignoring it. I recommend you read more about the differences between GET and POST and other HTTP verbs.

Comment: In your client code, you can add `print(response.request.body)` to see if the request body does in fact contain the JSON.

Comment: `print(response.request.body)` is giving None

Comment: That seems to confirm my guess in my answer below: `requests.get()` ignores the `json` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`requests.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) does not have a `json` argument. My guess is that this is just ignored in your client code. In fact, it is unusual to include any data in the body of a GET request in general.

You are probably confusing this with the `json` parameter for `requests.post()`. We always include data in the body of a POST request.

I recommend that you follow the [official Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/) to learn Django. It is a fullstack web application rather than an API, but it will be more accurate than this video.